# DWG file fonts not displaying

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I tried to load fonts with my drawing but i have an error <Missing fonts\nSome missing fonts were substituted for the drawing file: {0}>. I use https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/<BASE64_ENCODED_URN_OF_SOURCE_FILE>/references this route to add references to my drawing. Response what i get is { result: 'success' }. But when i open the viewer the fonts doesn't loaded.
Could you help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to upload the files, set up the references between them, and then translate them - not the other way round.

We have a step by step tutorial on this here: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-source-file-containing-xref/

Comment: thanks for the answer but i have already found the mistake. I open the drawing in the viewer before file was translated